# Prevent Cocos2D touches during animation?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touches

In this animation here:

```
    - (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    self.isTouchEnabled = NO;
    if (scoreLabel.opacity == 225) {
        NSLog(@"fadeOut");
        CCSequence *fadeOut = [CCSequence actions:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5], [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
        selector:@selector(enableTouches)], nil];
        [scoreLabel runAction:fadeOut];
        [livesLabel runAction:[[fadeOut copy] autorelease]];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"fadeIn");
        CCSequence *fadeIn = [CCSequence actions:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.5], [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
        selector:@selector(enableTouches)], nil];
        [scoreLabel runAction:fadeIn];
        [livesLabel runAction:[[fadeIn copy] autorelease]];
         }
}
```

I am trying to simply fade out/in labels. The thing is though, I want **to make sure** that this method won't get called while the labels are animating.

If you look in the code, I attempt to do that by calling this method:

```
    - (void)enableTouches {
    NSLog(@"ET");
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
}
```

But it does not seem to work. If I touch the screen while the labels are animating, it messes up the animation midway through and doesn't do what I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this in case anyone has the same issue:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    self.isTouchEnabled = NO;

    if(label1.opacity == 0 )
    {
        CCFadeIn* fadeIn = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.5];
        CCCallBlock* fadeCompleted = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ self.isTouchEnabled = YES; }];     

        [label1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeIn, fadeCompleted, nil]];
        [label2 runAction:[[fadeIn copy] autorelease]];
    }
    else
    {
        CCFadeOut* fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5];
        CCCallBlock* fadeCompleted = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ self.isTouchEnabled = YES; }];     

        [label1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeOut, fadeCompleted, nil]];
        [label2 runAction:[[fadeOut copy] autorelease]];
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative would have been to use a seperate BOOL variable that controls whether new touches are ignored while the label animates.

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't know, you can assign tags to actions the same way you can assign tags to nodes. Then you can call getActionByTag: on the object that is running the action to either get nil or a pointer to the action. By checking if the return value is nil or an action you will know if the certain action/animation you are looking for is playing. That way you might be able to do this without additional variables.